# Which word can be used to describe the lesson that introduce the content or usage of one chapter?

Tags: word-choice

Recently I have been working on the ***'mathematics introduction lesson'***. I want to find more theories and articles about this kind of lesson. However, I can't even get useful information by searching on Google Scholar with words like 'Mathematics introduction lesson', 'chapter beginning lesson','pre-chapter lesson' and similar words.

I want to know how an English native speaker would describe this kind of lesson, in order to search some papers.(I am not a English native speaker. I think my failure may be due to the wrong search words.)

Here, ***'mathematics introduction lesson'*** means this kind of lesson: in a mathematics lesson, before teaching a new chapter, the teacher tells students what they will learn, how to learn, the application of the knowledge in real life, or something more, all in one whole lesson. For example, in a ***mathematics introduction lesson*** before teaching the new chapter ***'trigonometric function'***: I will tell my students the history of its being invented, how designers use the function to measure structures, its usage in industry, any difficulties during the learning process, and how to study this new chapter.

Sorry for choosing the tag 'word-choice', for I do not know which tag is proper. If it's not right, please edit it to a proper one if you like.

Comment: As the kind of learner who wants examples over theory, I'd lose attention quickly if such a lesson took up the whole session. I couldn't absorb the things surrounding a *thing* when I don't know what the *thing* is yet. Rather than stir my interest, the lesson would make me think "And your point?" Math major here.

Comment: I finished my bachelor degree in math major too. When I was learning the complex analysis, the abstract algebra and some other courses(not all), my teacher always spent 30-45 minutes to tell us its history, the content, and something else. Now I am majoring in education for junior students, and there are some articles(of course not in English) discussing this kind of lesson. Some results indeedly show the opinion like yours, but some positive opinions also show that this kind of lesson could help students understand the knowledge they would learn is not only a complex character game.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- "*[Introductory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/introductory)*": of, relating to, or being a first step that sets something going or in proper perspective
- "*Overview*"
- "*Background*"
- "*[Motivation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/motive)*": something (such as a need or desire) that causes a person to act

For example, "*Introductory lesson*", "*background and motivation*", "*trigonometry overview*" or "*calculus background*".

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer to readers. You are talking of some sort of "Introduction to ...", perhaps "an introductory lesson", The choice of term is to some extent a matter of opinion, which is why I do not give an answer: on this site we do not give opinions as answers.

Comment: The question is asking for vocabulary which describes a context-giving lesson. It's not about what I would call this lesson but a suggested list of words (with references) which could help them better search their subject literature. I don't feel this is an opinion answer.